# IOS - Como realizar envio de um E-mail informando o destinatário?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Estou tentando enviar um E-mail com o destinatário já informado, mas não sei como passar esta informação no código.

## Código:

```
-(IBAction) mail : (id) sender{
    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"test mail"];
    [mailcomposer setMessageBody:@"Msg teste do Mail"
                          isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
}
```

Utilizei também MessageUI.framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método **setToRecipients** do MFMailComposeViewController. 
Vale lembrar que como você pode enviar para mais de um destinatário, sendo assim, o método irá esperar um array de entrada.

*OBS:O método precisa ser chamado antes da exibição da view na tela. Após a exibição da view, esse método não estará mais disponível.*

Exemplos:

Passando um email fixo:

```
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@email.com",nil]];
```

Passando um email que poderá variar:

```
NSArray *arrayQueVemDeAlgumLugar = @["email@email.com"];
[picker setToRecipients:arrayQueVemDeAlgumLugar;
```

Mais de um email:

```
[picker setToRecipients:@[@"email@email.com", @"email2@email.com", nil]];
```

Lembrando, que o padrão com que você cria/passa o array via parâmetro pode mudar conforme você ache mais legível.

[Caso queira ver mais informações sobre como funciona o MFMailComposer](http://www.codingexplorer.com/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-email-in-your-apps/)